# How should I connect my bath fan to the three cables in the ceiling?

Tags: wiring, fans, exhaust

I have red-white-black wires coming from my switch and 2 sets of house wires (black-white-grnd). Can someone tell me how to tie these together with a new fan that has two white, one black and one blue wire?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Model # of fan, pictures of existing wiring and knowing what was there before (a different fan, a light, both?) would help.

Comment: Nu Tone HB80RL is going in. Nu Tone fan/light removed. No model number but it had black/white going to the fan plug and red/white/yellow to the light.

Comment: New information belongs in your question, please, not down here. Take the [tour] to learn more.

Comment: Yes, [edit] the question to add data.  The first clue here is the black tape tagging the white wire in the /3 cable.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and expertise! One more thing. I like the single switch because it's a timer switch. Don't need my kids leaving things on all day and there is another light fixture in the room. So leaving it as is, how does the wiring go?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything was done the "usual" way:

Switch cable:

- Black & Red = switched hots - connect one to fan black and one to fan blue (doesn't matter electrically, but which one you choose will determine which switch controls fan vs. light)
- White = hot. Normally white is neutral, but if you have a cable with black/red/white being used for hot + two switched hot, white is used as the always hot and marked (as shown) with black tape or marker. Connect to the blacks in the other 2 cables.

Other cables:

- All blacks together and connected to white-marked-black from switch cable.
- All whites together and connected to whites from new fan/light.

One of those cables is incoming power. The other goes someplace else - e.g., another light or receptacle. There is almost certainly something else that stopped working when you took this all apart - i.e., if you capped all these wires instead of connecting together, and then turned the breaker on, you'd find something somewhere that doesn't work. But if you connect everything together again, whatever was disconnected will be reconnected and work.

Use [wire nuts](https://amzn.to/3l7hqvG), not tape, to connect wires together. Tape is great for marking and for protecting but can't be used to make a permanent connection.

[image: wire nuts]

Wire nuts come in multiple sizes - in particular, the smallest typical wire nuts may not be enough for 4 white wires (neutrals from two cables + fan & light neutrals).

A little more based on comments:

Since you currently have just one switch for both light & fan, you may want to consider splitting to two switches, since you have a 3-wire cable. There are two reasons to do this:

- Fan without light - with LED lighting using very little power, this is not a big deal, but it still saves a little energy if you want to run the fan for a while after you are done with a shower.
- Light without fan - this can be *very* useful. A lot of people don't like the noise of fans, so if you are brushing your teeth or doing any other activity that doesn't generate a lot of humidity or strong odors, there really is no need to have the fan on.

Assuming you have a typical 1-gang switch (regular or Decora) and not already a combination switch/receptacle, you can replace it with a [double switch](https://amzn.to/2UVUDby):

[image: Leviton double switch]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I should say though that i just have one switch for light and fan. I actually put the tape on the white wire because it was not tied to the other 2 white wires

Comment: And "not tied to the other white wires" == "not neutral" == "put black tape on it because it is hot". So you did the right thing!

Comment: Aha! Not just a simple switch. What I would do is change the other light switch into a double and use that for the two lights (separate and "light that goes with fan") and use the timer just for the fan. Exactly how to do that will depend on how things are wired up now, but really shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: Well, that is an entirely different story. If I understand correctly, you are simply trying to make the fan/light "equivalent to previous". That was one switch, so one switch still.

Comment: In Europe neutral wire is blue.

Comment: @user263983 Based on Nutone model and picture showing black/white/red NM cable, this is US/Canada.